# Video URI/URl is not fetched using Photo Library plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**What I tried below:**

**Step 1:** tried following this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/photo-library.

**Step 2:** I have install this below command

> $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-photo-library
> $ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/photo-library

**Step 3:** Below code for reference

```
   import { PhotoLibrary } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/photo-library/ngx';

constructor(private photoLibrary: PhotoLibrary) { }

this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization().then(() => {
this.photoLibrary.getLibrary().subscribe({
 next: library => {
   library.forEach(function(libraryItem) {
     console.log(libraryItem.id);          // ID of the photo
     console.log(libraryItem.photoURL);    // Cross-platform access to photo
     console.log(libraryItem.thumbnailURL);// Cross-platform access to thumbnail
     console.log(libraryItem.fileName);    // array of ids of appropriate AlbumItem, only of includeAlbumsData was used
   });
 },
 error: err => { console.log('could not get photos'); },
 complete: () => { console.log('done getting photos'); }
});
})
.catch(err => console.log('permissions weren\'t granted'));
```

**Problem I'm facing:**

1. in the console.log i'm not able to find any video provided from the gallery

**Workaround based on my research**

1. We need to provide the `onst options: GetLibraryOptions = {includeVideos:true};`  as parameter in the `getLibrary()` method.
2. but I'm not able to send the options as parameter in the getlibrary method

How to print the videos from gallery using this options.

**Please let me know how to get all the videos and images from the gallery without opening the gallery.**